# Geometric intuition behind linear system Ax=B? between ways of view?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, systems-of-equations

I'm trying to pool how people see a simple **Ax=B** system from
a geometric point of view.
So far, I can regard it, 
as a set of equations, that can be viewed as hyperplanes,
or as linear combinations of column vectors scaled by x components that would reach B, or as seeing B as coordinates from identity to X, this one in local coordinates to transformation axes A.

I'm always asking myself if, those ideas are related between them by geometric means; I mean, if you could use a compass, rulers, protractor, draw unit circles, etc, transfer vector components to others dimensions or so, we would reach to a unified view of those?

I'm very dull at maths, thanks for the help.

Comment: It's an intersection of $(n-1)$-dimensional flat surfaces embedded in $n$-dimensional space, so lines in the plane, planes in 3D space, etc.

Comment: i'm afraid that is only the hyperplane view. what i'm trying to ask, is if it would be possible a geometrically way to build a cohesive linking between the two views  having simple geometric tools (using orthogonality, straight lines, unit spheres etc) to connect them.

Comment: I think your question is very broad. Could you narrow it down?

Comment: why very broad? just imagine that you have two whiteboards and draw there two cartesian axes: in the first whiteboard draw the lines resulting of the equations, at the second the span of the vectors. i'm asking for a geometric cohese connection between the two drawings using geometry. is up to people to grasp their minds and write here. not to narrow minds.

Comment: Up to 3-dimensions, sure! You can think of linear system solutions as intersections of planes

Answer (score 0):

well i managed to have some kind of view to a simple A (2x2) x (2x1) = B (2x1), there are for sure many other possibilities.
Assuming that the hyperplane equations are normalized, A, b to n/||n|| . x = ||n||

I used 2 cartesian planes rotated by 90º in y axis, around the unit center, then:

- draw the same column vectors of A (A:1,A:2) and B on the two planes
- draw also the A vectors (A:1 x1,A:2 x2) scaled until the sum reaches B
- transfer the x coordinates of both vectors to the center making the first transpose vector of A (A1:,A2:);
- rotate 90º in (cartesian planes local) z, the y coordinates of both column vectors of A and B and transfer to the center, making the second transpose vector of B;
- this will result on the row vectors of A and quantities of B laying on the z plane
- use the transfered B quantities to make two circles
- scale the transpose vectors of A to the B circles, both already on a z plane with that common center (they should be the true normals to the line equations, since A rows are unit vectors)
- draw the ortogonal lines passing by those last, and make the proper intersection
- assuming that the cartesian planes are on z = 1, draw a ray one unit behind each cartesian plane on their z axis, passing to each of the column vectors; for both planes, bring the planes to, aligning it to the scaled A column vectors; the quantity laying on the z axis of the planes would be the X scales (analog to homogeneous coordinates)
- now transfer those scales laying in both z-axis (local to the each cartesian plane) by 1 and 1-x1, to the center, they should align equally to the x, z coordinates of the intersection.

the symmetry isnt good, because i had to rotate the 2nd set of y-coordinates to get the transposes. Also in the last push, i had to correct the last push to 1-x1. but this is the best i could get.

the whole cenario looks like a cdrom:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

sorry if my question wasn't clear enough, i wanted a geometric setting for a simple Ax=B showing those two views, just using rotations and translations.